# PacketRouting from host on VM(Win 7 x64)

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, routing, wireguard, proxmox

I have WireGuard installed on my host and VM. I connect to host machine's WireGuard. I need the packets to pass through the host system and get to the VM into the WireGuard of my VM and then out to the Internet.

How can I do this?

cat /etc/network/interface (on host):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
address XXX.XX.XX.XXX/24
gateway XXX.XX.XX.1

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
address 10.10.0.1/24
bridge_ports none
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0

post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.0.0/24' -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.0.0/24' -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
post-up iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
```

I've only tried this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vmbr1 -j MASQUERADE 
ip route add default via 10.10.0.4 dev vmbr1 table 7    //ip VM  
ip rule add from 10.10.0.10/32 table 7              // wg0 subnet (vpn)
```